# Adding text beneath signature on reply and forward

Tags: vba, outlook

This code adds my defined text after the last paragraph of newly composed emails.

I need to identify the area beneath the signature when composing a reply or content to be forwarded, as the code will add my text to the last paragraph of the whole email thread.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
Dim recip As Outlook.recipient
Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Dim prompt, strMsg, myText As String
Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector

myText = "HERE IS THE TEXT TO BE ADDED"


Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Set recips = Item.Recipients
For Each recip In recips
    Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
    If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@nhs.net") = 0 Then
        strMsg = strMsg & "   " & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next


Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
If oInspector Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No active inspector"
Else
    Set NewMail = oInspector.CurrentItem
    If NewMail.Sent Then
        MsgBox "This is not an editable email"
    Else
        If oInspector.IsWordMail Then

            Dim oDoc As Object, oWrdApp As Object, oSelection As Object
            Set oDoc = oInspector.WordEditor
            Set oWrdApp = oDoc.Application

                If strMsg = "" Then 'All the recipients are internal to the organisation.

                    'Add contact line to bottom of signature
                     oWrdApp.ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter myText
                       With oWrdApp.ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Last
                          .Range.Font.Bold = True
                          .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                        End With
                End If

            Set oWrdApp = Nothing
            Set oDoc = Nothing

        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

On a new message, where all the recipients are internal to the NHS (@nhs.net domain) a contact line will be added beneath the signature.

> Dear Somebody,
>       Here is the body of my email!
>       Kind Regards,
>       TM
>
> Here is my sig
>       ** and here is the line added by the VBA **

If I reply to an email or forward an email (and all the recipients are internal to the organisation) I incorrectly get:

> Hi Somebody,
>       Thanks for your reply. Here's what I think ......
>
> Good to hear from you,
>       TM
>
> Here is my sig
>
> ---
>
> From: Somebody
>       Sent: Sometime
>
> Hi TM,
>       Here's the reply to your original email!
>       Thanks,
>       Somebody
>
> ---
>
> From: TM
>       Sent: Initial email
>       Dear Somebody,
>       Here is the body of my email!
>       Kind Regards,
>       TM
>
> Here is my sig
>       ** and here is the line added by the VBA **initially** **
>       **** This is the line added by the VBA when I reply or fwd ****
>       **** It needs to be beneath the signature in the email currently being drafted!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work by the time the message is actually sent (`Application.ItemSend` event), but while the inspector is still active, you can find the beginning of the original email using using the "_MailOriginal" bookmark. You can then insert your text just before it. `objDoc` below comes from `Inspector.WordEditor`

```
If objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailOriginal") Then
  set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailOriginal")
  objSel.Start = objBkm.Start-2 'give room for the line break before. It includes the line
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously I would have suggested the unreliable "From:" as the demarcation point between new and original text.

Given now the bookmark "_MailOriginal" that appears to be reliable you can insert above that point.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim recips As Recipients
Dim recip As Recipient

Dim pa As propertyAccessor

Dim strMsg As String
Dim myText As String

Dim oInspector As Inspector

Dim oDoc As Object

Dim oBkm As Object
Dim oSel As Object

myText = "HERE IS THE TEXT TO BE ADDED"

Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Set recips = Item.Recipients

For Each recip In recips
    Set pa = recip.propertyAccessor
    If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@nhs.net") = 0 Then
        strMsg = pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) & vbNewLine
        Exit For    'One recipient is enough
    End If
Next

If strMsg <> "" Then
    'All the recipients are internal to the organisation.
    GoTo ExitRoutine
End If

Set oInspector = Item.GetInspector

If oInspector.IsWordMail Then

    Set oDoc = oInspector.WordEditor

    If oDoc.Bookmarks.exists("_MailOriginal") Then

        Set oBkm = oDoc.Bookmarks("_MailOriginal")
        oBkm.Select
        Set oSel = oDoc.Windows(1).Selection

        With oSel
            .InsertBefore myText & vbNewLine
            .Collapse
            .MoveEnd Unit:=wdLine, count:=1
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        End With

    Else

        'Add contact line to bottom of signature
        oDoc.Content.InsertAfter myText
        With oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.last
            .Range.Font.Bold = True
            .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        End With

    End If

End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set recips = Nothing
    Set recip = Nothing
    Set pa = Nothing

    Set oInspector = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set oBkm = Nothing
    Set oSel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the revised code. I tested it and it behaves the same as the current code, when both forwarded, and replied. I tried with "_MailAutoSig" too but no dice, perhaps relevant that it's Outlook 2007

Comment: Actually the "_MailAutoSig" bookmark is hidden and the "_MailOriginal" doesn't exist!